# How to get color property from CSS with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, colors

I want to add an animation to all links' color change. I mean, without any Javascript, when a link is hovered, its color changes immediately. What I want to do is, when you hover a link, its color should change step by step with jQuery's *$.animate* function.

It's easy to do until here. But the thing is, I don't want to write the RGB code for each of the link types. I want jQuery to know what color a link has to be when it's hovered.

If you didn't understand me until here, let me explain it with an example:

```
$('a').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate( { 'color', $(this + ':hover').css('color') }, { duration: 250 });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate( { 'color', $(this).css('color') }, { duration: 250 });
});
```

I know this code won't work, but I think it explains what I need clearly.

Comment: Did you consider css3 transition for this effect? It would be the easier and more performant way to do this kind of effect.

Comment: CSS3 Transitions are really the way to go for the effect you're trying to achieve. The browser support isn't very good but it's getting better and even if you find a jQuery plugin that helps with this effect it's probably abandoned and really buggy.

Comment: I tried CSS3 transitions. But it's not supported in IE. My design has to support IE. So I can't use it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CSS3 transitions:
http://jsfiddle.net/wsZKQ/1/

```
a{
    -moz-transition:all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.25s;
    transition:all 0.25s;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

If you want to do it with jQuery, you need a plugin for accessing the `:hover`-styles:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/moreSelectors

I don't think there is a way to access the `:hover` styles without a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = $('element').css('color');
```

If you set via RGB such as rgb(red,green,blue) style you don't have to do hex transforms. You could easily change colors from 0-255.

I've done similar things with RGB take a look at http://www.homeschoolsnowboarding.com be patient and watch the background slowly change colors.